# Internext Explorer dropdown menu hover disappearing

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7, hover, submenu

I've got this site I have put together www.endosa.com, and unfortunately someone in the office has a dinosaur machine with ie7 on it.  They had some problems with the one dropdown menu on the site in the nav.  I've spent a few hours trying to get this thing to work.

Initially, it was appearing behind the next div, but I got that figured out with some z-index work.  Now, it appears correctly when it is hovered over, but when I try to put my mouse over the sub menu, the list disappears.

Any ideas?

Comment: `nav.primary ul li{ display:inline; }` is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue also appears on chrome.

This is because you positioned your subnav absolute 100% but not relative to the parent element it's relative to your header element.

http://pastebin.com/u07XYUvC

I fixed your header (at least for the desktop query, I didn't check the others) so subnav is relative to the top level 'li' item & main navigation is positioned at the bottom of the header.

You are using a lot of margins to position elements that require absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, these helped a lot. I think i have it figured out and t's working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
nav.primary ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```